# Vim plugin: indentLine, not showing indent guides for bash file (no shebang) just named [file].bash

Tags: plugin, plugin-indentline

Plugin: [indentLine](https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine)

I'm not getting indent lines for `bash` files (and `Java` files but not important as I use `IntelliJ`), using this plugin, it only shows indent lines for `Python`

- I installed using `Pathogen` plugin manager.
- I only use spaces not tabs.

`~/.vimrc` settings given to me by a commentator:

```
let g:indentLine_enabled = 1
let g:indentLine_char = '│'
" Don't forget to add a space after the \
set listchars+=lead:\
```

The only alternative plugin give thick ugly indent guides, which I don't want [vim-indent-guides](https://github.com/preservim/vim-indent-guides).

The following values are the same for both the `bash`, `Python`, and `Java` files:

- `et`=\ (space)
- `sw`=8
- `st`=8

Screenshot of `~/.vimrc` (sourced):
[image]

Screenshot of bashfile with options set from last comment by answerer:

[image]

Also tried the above with a bash file with just an if statement, I got the dots, but no indent guides after running `:indentlinenable` (spelling incorrect here but it autocompleted) and toggle commands.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because requests for plugins are off-topic. Questions about how to achieve specific behavior may be answered by suggesting a plugin, however.

Comment: Comments are for clarifying questions, constructive criticism, and minor but transient related information. Let's keep it civil, folks.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I edited the question to fit the specifications.

Comment: It seems like you have an entirely new question (the existing answer would be a poor answer). Is that right? If so, it's probably easier to create a new Question (you can copy-paste the "raw" question by pressing [edit] here).

Comment: Yes I've had to ask a new question as this plugin is the only one that meets my needs, I think the answer is good, as I'm getting somewhere and the answerer has demonstrated it works

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot of the bash file. For the excerpt of your `vmrc` file it would be better if you post the text instead of the screenshot. Screenshot are supposed to only be used to describe visual problem.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me: if the question is so new that it makes obsolete existing answers, please ask a new question.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble could you please re-open and pretend the original question wasn't asked? :) The answerer went through a lot of effort to help, and also tailored their answer to my needs (the vimrc settings).

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt it sounds like you have provided an answer to this new question that differs from what’s in the box below. I’d feel more comfortable re-opening the Q if the answer reflected that (I can clean up unneeded comments later).

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean by "in the box below" but feel free to do anything that you believe is appropriate I fully trust you :-). The valuable part of the "chat" has been moved to the answer or the question. I see no problem if we lose part or the full "chat".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popular choices for Vim are:

- [indentLine](https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine) working but not maintained
- [vim-indent-guides](https://github.com/preservim/vim-indent-guides)

The first is probably the one that match your demand the most.
Here is some configuration that makes it closer to what I believe you expect:

```
let g:indentLine_enabled = 1
let g:indentLine_char = '│'
" Don't forget to add a space after the \
set listchars+=lead:\ 
" set nolist
```

Remark: Don't forget to add a space after the `\`:

`set listchars+=lead:\`

If you are using tabulation you can do:

```
set list
set listchars+=lead:\ 
set listchars+=\|\
```

Remark: Don't forget to add a space after the `\`:

- `set listchars+=lead:\`
- `set listchars+=tab:\|\`

Here is the result for the [afterglow](https://github.com/danilo-augusto/vim-afterglow) colorscheme with space as indentation character (`:set et`)

[image]

Here is a result for a `bash` file (with the Nord colorscheme):
[image]

For the following file content:

```bash
foo='${1}'
baz="${1}"

if ["${foo}" == "baz"]; then
    bar=""
elif [ "${foo}" == "baz" ]; then
    bar=oof
    if [ "${bar}" == "grr" ]; then
        bar=rab
        foo=foo
        if [ "${bar}" == "rrg" ]; then
            bar=bar
            foo=oof
        fi
    fi
fi

# vim:ts=4:sw=4:et:
```

I encourage you to test the content of the file to verify it works fine for you.

Comment: I have Pathogen is my plugin manager, cloned the first repo to `~/.vim/bundle` copied your settings to `~/.vimrc` (left a space for that var) and sourced, no indent guides appeared, tried running `:IndentLinesToggle` nothing happened, this was with a Java and bash file. Tried running `:echo has('conceal')` which returned 1 (so I must have it), not sure why this didn't work.

Comment: I'll go to a trip for two days I'll test it for java when I'm back. I'm coding in Python where it works well. Strange that it doesn't work for you.  Which version of Vim are you using? Which OS (Ubuntu, MacOs, ...)? Which colorscheme?

Comment: Two more question: Do you use tab or spaced to indent your code? What is the value of `:set list`?

Comment: I have updated the solution to provide a solution for tab based indentation. Does it help?

Comment: I tried on Bash and java, I only use spaces even in python, I'll retry. Apologies this is on macos that's probably the issue... colorscheme is `afterglow` I'll check `set list` value

Comment: vim 9.1, when I do `:set list` it just shows the same as usual, `$` at the end of lines or before whitespace

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I don't have access MacOs but it should work just fine.

Comment: I believe you've helped me out before, I think I'm still having issues, if I give you the answer on this one will you even get credit? I'll open a new one  if not

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) What is the current status. Do we have some improvement from the start or not at all :-) I believe you have the plugin installed since you have access to the command but what is the result? May be a screenshot would help.

Comment: I read too quickly your answer. Don't be too worry about my crédit  :-) It is more important to me that the problem are solved and the solution published :-)

Comment: it works fine with python but not bash or java:(

Comment: Do you indent java code with spaces or tab? What is the result of `:set et?`, :set sw?` and `:set ts?` on a java buffer?

Comment: `et`=space, `sw`=8 , `ts`=8 for both the python file and bash file (I use IntelliJ for java so don't care about that), do you get lines for bash files? no shebang, just named `file.bash`

Comment: Do you really have space to indent your code? Can you move through the indentation and hit `ga` to see which character are there? What if you run the following Vim command `:retab`?

Comment: It seems to work fine for the `.bash` file for me.

Comment: I would be interested to get a screenshot with `:set listchars+=lead:.,tab:->`  and `:set list`.

Comment: Shall I add this as a new question as it's staying closed?

I added screenshots of what you said to set above, I also tried with a bash file with just an if statement and still didn't get indent guides, also tried with nord colorscheme.

Also tried adding the options in the `~/.vimrc` manually while in Vim but no luck.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot :-) The indentation  of the the seems slightly inconsistant some time 2 spaces are used some time four spaces. I'm interested to the value of `tabstop` and `shiftwidth`. Could you tell me what is the result of `:set ts?` and `:set sw?`. If both are 8 and you are indenting with 2 spaces it will not work. Maybe you could run the following command on the buffer: `:set ts=2, `:set sw=2` and have some text with a doublé indentation (4 spaces) à tin vertical line should appear for those at the 3 column.

Comment: I set it to `sw=3` and changed my indent style a bit. The reason it wasn't showing anything is because `sw=8`, only at `sw=6` do the lines appear, thanks for solving this. For some reason by default `sw=8` for my vim, as the lines didn't show for an if statement indented with 4 spaces.

Comment: can I set `sw` to different values depending on the file type? Could ask a different question for that actually.

Comment: Great :-) Ask another question. I'll explain you how to do :-)

Comment: Seems that someone asked this question and it was a duplicate... this plugin [vim-sleuth](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sleuth), seems to automatically change the value of sw based on indent, however if it doesn't work out I'll see if I could ask the question in a different way. Your help is much appreciated :)

Comment: I have created a [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/43839/how-to-have-different-identation-style-per-file/43840#43840) to gather my knownledge about setting the indentation options of a file.

Comment: Btw: [chat] is better suited to extended conversations.

Comment: Officially I have tried many times to move people to the chat but I never succeeded. I lose people when we go to the chat. I suspect they are not informed about new message. If you have advice to move people to the chat there are welcome ;-)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Vivian had tried to move to chat. Thank you for the innovative suggestion, albeit you are several days late, nevertheless it is very much appreciated.