# How to have different indentation styles depending on the file?

Tags: indentation

The way the code needs to be indented depends on the `filetype`.

How can I configure Vim to use the correct value of `tabstop`, `shiftwidth` and `expandtab` depending on the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## By file type

If the value of these option only depend on the `filetype` you can override the default for a specific file type (e.g.: python) by adding a `./vim/after/ftplugin/`*filetype*`.vim` with the desired content.

e.g.: to ask Vim to indent cpp files using tab of 6 characters size instead of 4 spaces you could add a:

`~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim` with the following content:

```
setlocal noexpandtab
setlocal shiftwidth=6
setlocal tabstop=6
```

e.g.: to ask Vim to indent python file using tab of 2 characters size instead of 4 spaces you could add a:

`~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` with the following content:

```
setlocal noexpandtab
setlocal shiftwidth=2
setlocal tabstop=2
```

Remark: this will work if the following command has been executed (typically in your `.vimrc` file)

```
filetype plugin on
```

Remark: if you have no `.vimrc` a default `.vimrc` will be executed by Vim that contains that command.

Remark:

- On Windows you have to replace `~/.vim` by `~/vimfiles`
- For Neovim you have to replace `~/.vim` by `~/.config/nvim`

## By file

If your the indentation depends not only on the `filetype` but on the file itself you can use a `modeline` at the start or at the end of the file. A `modeline` is a comment with a specific syntax that Vim uses to set some buffer specific options.

e.g.: To have a specific `cpp` file that use tabs of 6 character size instead of 4 spaces for indentation you could add the following line in your cpp file:

```
// vim:ts=6:sw=6:noet:
```

e.g.: To have a specific `python` file that use tabs of 2 character size instead of 4 spaces for indentation you could add the following line in your python script:

```
# vim:ts=2:sw=2:noet:
```

More information about `modeline` with [:help modeline](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#modeline)

## By project

If your indentation settings depend on the project (the child file from a root directory) you can use the [editorconfig](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vim) plugin.

To have:

- The `cpp` file of your project indented with tabs of 6 characters size
- The `python` file of your project indented with tabs of 2 characters size
  you can have a `.editorconfig` file at the root of your project with the following content:

```
[*.cpp]
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 6
[*.py]
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 2
```

Remark (thanks to @romainl for that): Starting with Vim 9.1 the `editorconfig` plugin is now distributed together with Vim. You can activate it by adding the following line to your `.vimrc` file:

```
packadd! editorconfig
```

More information with: [:help editorconfig-install](https://vimhelp.org/usr_05.txt.html#editorconfig-install)

More information about the format in the [documentation](https://editorconfig.org/) page.

## Ask a Vim plugin to guess

You can also use the [vim-sleuth](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sleuth) to guess these settings based on the content of the file.

There are various alternatives:

- [vim-sleuth](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sleuth)
- [detectindent](https://github.com/ciaranm/detectindent)

Comment: Note that the editorconfig plugin is now distributed with Vim: `:help editorconfig`.

Comment: Nice write up (although I would have hoped to find something like this in Vim's `:help` somewhere). I have a minor objection to using Python with non-[PEP-8 compliant indentation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#indentation) as an example. Other languages are far more liberal when it comes to whitespace.

Comment: Thanks @romainl for letting me know.

Comment: @Friedrich, I understand but to demonstrate the example I should use value that differs from the Vim standard. Maybe should I use `cpp` where the norm is less shared?

Comment: My concern is that people tend to copy stuff verbatim, without ever thinking. I would hate to see tab indented Python code crop up as a result of your answer. With C or C++, anything from 2 (to make McCabe unhappy) to 8 (to make Linus happy) goes. [Edit: you already edited while I was typing...]

Comment: It's "modeline", not "modline". And Vim doesn't guess anything, it is those plugins that do.

Comment: I have corrected the typo and modify the subtitle (I was already hesitating during the redaction ;-) ).

Comment: @romainl that was very astute observation through all that information we are all very glad you caught that missing 'e,' I was losing my mind about it until I seen your comment.